# How to avoid page refresh after selectedindexchanged of dropdown list?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using update panel and ASP drop down. When I select any value from a drop down list I load some data from a database that depends on this selected value. However, whenever this selection changes the page will be refreshed. How can I avoid this page refresh? I have also tried AsyncPostBackTrigger but still this problem occurs.

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="false">
   </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="OuterUpdatePanel" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddList" CssClass="dropdown" Style="width: 200px !important;"
                 runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddList_SelectedIndexChanged">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 6):

Add this, if you want the dropdownlist to trigger Ajax call without refreshing the page and do not remove `AutoPostBack="true"`

```
<Triggers> 
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddList" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" /> 
</Triggers>
```

Comment: i have checked this and also with <asp:PostBackTrigger... but problem is still there

Comment: Are you adding the triggers below content template? And secondly do not remove AutoPostBack="true"

Comment: yes below content template and all other controls are in content template.

Comment: Check to make sure you don't have any controls with ClientIDMode=Static within the updatepanel, make them inherit.

Comment: i have table, labels, buttons and some other drop down lists in content template and no one have ClientIDMode=Static

Comment: Try to remove the dropdownlist outside updatepanel and see it works or delete files in the bin and rebuild your solution. See, if any one of the two works for you.

Answer (score 4):

The crux of your question, I believe, is:

"when i select any value from drop down i load some data from database that depends on this selected value, i am facing a problem whenever selection changes page will be refreshed."

There are many ways to accomplish this, but it might require some restructuring to produce the desired effect.  A relatively simple way to do this would be:

(1) Reorganize your page as follows:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddList" CssClass="dropdown" Style="width: 200px !important;" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="OuterUpdatePanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
        <!-- Content goes here -->
        </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

(2) Add script as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function handleDDLChange() {
  __doPostBack($('div[id$="OuterUpdatePanel"]').attr('id'), 'ddlList_Changed_Or_Anything_Else_You_Might_Want_To_Key_Off_Of');
}

$('input[id$="ddlList"]').change( handleDDLChange );
</script>
```

This is a more "old-school" approach, but it should solve your issue.

EDIT:  The following illustrates a "non-jQuery" approach, with the above idea a little more fleshed out:

ASCX:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlList" runat="server" onchange="handleDDLChange()">
    <asp:ListItem Text="text1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="text2" />
</asp:DropDownList>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleDDLChange() {
        __doPostBack("<%= ddlList.ClientID %>", "ddlList_Changed_Or_Anything_Else_You_Might_Want_To_Key_Off_Of");
    }
</script>

 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:Literal ID="litTest" runat="server" />
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code-Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        litTest.Text = "No postback";
    }
    else if (Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] == "ddlList_Changed_Or_Anything_Else_You_Might_Want_To_Key_Off_Of")
    {
        litTest.Text = string.Format("Dropdown changed: {0}", ddlList.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        litTest.Text = "Postback for some other reason... :(";
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any other solution without jQuery?

Comment: I've amended my answer to include more specific code that does not rely on jQuery selectors